# Extend Dispatch time for dispatch_after

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have the following code in a method:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0f;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

If the method is called before `delayInSeconds` is up, I would like to extend the timer by another two seconds. and then execute the block. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that is possible as soon as the block is dispatched within its delay time. You could add another dispatch_after within the block and set its time accordingly to 0 or 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I would recommend not to use gcd for that. Instead you can try:

> [self performSelector:@selector(anyMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourDelay]
>
> //Then if you need to cancel just do:
>
> [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(anyMethod) object:nil]
>
> //And simply reschedule your timer here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSTimer`:

```
- (void)someFunctionThatGetsCalledMoreThanOnce {
    ...

    [_myTimer invalidate];
    _myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 
                                       target:self 
                                     selector:@selector(doStuff:) 
                                     userInfo:nil 
                                      repeats:NO];

    ...
}

- (void)doStuff:(NSTimer*)timer {
    // Do some stuff
}
```